# Best Practice to Develop IPhone and Android App UI using Titanium

Tags: android, iphone, titanium

We are starting the development of an Android and IPhone app and wanted to know if the best practice on developing the UI for both environments.

We have developed the core (functionality) for both the environments as common classes. The core does not have dependency on the UI at all.

Is the best practice to have separate UI code for IPhone and Android or should they be combined together and where required conditionally written?

I would like to understand this as you may have come across situations like this.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043896/what-are-the-best-practices-for-developing-applications-using-titanium-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appcelerator has two recommended methods for creating cross-platform UIs - branching and platform-specific commonJS.

In my experience the use of platform-specific commonJS has been the easiest to maintain, although it does require a little extra work up front.

The section on [supporting multiple platforms in a single code base](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/Supporting_Multiple_Platforms_in_a_Single_Codebase) in the Titanium 2.0 documentation goes into greater detail on this subject and should be helpful in choosing the path that's right for you.

A good example of creating cross platform UIs is the [community app](https://github.com/appcelerator-titans/App) created by Appcelerator's Titans program.